# Python: "__init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given” with Webdriver, when the element locator info is pulled from a separate file

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pageobjects

I am fairly new to Python and Selenium, and am trying to get some automated testing of our website off the ground. I am setting the tests up using the page object model so that changes to locators only need to be updated in one place. As part of this, I am setting up a function to wait for our subscribe button to be clickable. However, when I call this function I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "click_subscribe_button_test.py", line 51, in test_subscribe_click
main_page.wait_subscribe_button_clickable()
File "page.py", line 64, in wait_subscribe_button_clickable
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((*MainPageLocators.subscribe_button)))
TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

I have read a number of related posts on here and other sites, and while they have helped me get closer to solving the issue, I am still encountering the above error. The relevant code is below, it is from two separate files as the locators are in a different file than the page objects.

page.py

```
def wait_subscribe_button_clickable(self):
    subscribeElement =  self.driver.find_element(*MainPageLocators.subscribe_button)
    wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver,20)
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((*MainPageLocators.subscribe_button)))
```

locators.py

```
class MainPageLocators (object):
    subscribe_button = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'li.last.leaf.subscribe')
```

The problem seems to be around the way I am pulling the locators from a separate file, since if I change

```
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((*MainPageLocators.subscribe_button)))
```

to

```
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'li.last.leaf.subscribe')))
```

The code works as intended.

There may be something I do not understand about how the *MainPageLocators.subscribe_button function is pulling the locators, but I have not been able to track down what is wrong.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just *don't unpack the locator at all*, pass it as is, as a tuple:

```
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(MainPageLocators.subscribe_button))
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked great. Also points me to the next area to learn about. I appreciate the help.